# Many-To-Many relationship, Bidirectional, but I can't edit Categories for Task

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, associations

I'm training with Entities and generating CRUD controller for my Entities. I did Task and Category Entities:

**Category Entity**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    private $tasks;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->tasks = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getTasks()
    {
        return $this->tasks;
    }

    public function setTasks(Task $task)
    {
        $this->tasks = $task;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

?>
```

**Task Entity**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Task
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="task")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TaskRepository")
 */
class Task
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="datetime", type="datetime")
     */
    private $datetime;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="tasks")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="categories_tasks")
     */
    private $categories;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set datetime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $datetime
     *
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setDatetime($datetime)
    {
        $this->datetime = $datetime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get datetime
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDatetime()
    {
        return $this->datetime;
    }

    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function setCategories(Category $categories)
    {
        $this->categories = $categories;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

?>
```

I generated CRUD controllers for that Entities and it works almost fine - I can edit categories for Task. When I add new Task I also can choose 0, 1 or more categories. But it's not working in second way. When I add new category or edit existed I can choose 0, 1 or more categories from select list, I "save" and it goes further without exceptions but when I check in database or simply editing this category chosen tasks are not matched. I see category in database but `@ORM\JoinTable(name="categories_tasks")` has no new row. I think it has relation with `@ORM\JoinTable(name="categories_tasks")` because when I moved that part of code to `Category` Entity then I had inverse situation.

Comment: ( But it's not working in second way. When I add new category or edit existed I can choose 0, 1 or more categories from select list, I "save" )
Did you mean to say I choose 0, 1 more tasks? Since you are describing the other way around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task entity here is the relationship owner(it has the inversedBy annotation in the class), that is why adding categories to tasks then saving saves the categories to the relationship. For the categories to set the relationships you need to iterate through the tasks and have them set the id of the category, then save the tasks.

Not sure if there is a better solution. But I am confident of my diagnosis of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. When I used bidirectional relation I thought that it will make Task and Category equivalent in this meaning that I will manage easily both types. Maybe you now if there is some other type of association which doesn't set owner of set two owners?

Comment: Nope, I don't think it can be done. See here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html It mentions that owning sides exist even in many to many and relationship owners are the only ones that can modify the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to setup your `addCategory`, `removeCategory` and also `addTask` , `removeTask` methods properly:

Task.php

```
public function addCategory(Category $category)
{
    if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
        $this->categories->add($category);
        $category->addTask($this);
    }
}

public function removeCategory(Category $category)
{
    if ($this->categories->contains($category)) {
        $this->categories->remove($category);
        $category->removeTask($this);
    }
}
```

Same for Category.php

```
public function addTask(Task $task)
{
    if (!$this->tasks->contains($task)) {
        $this->tasks->add($task);
        $task->addCategory($this);
    }
}

public function removeTask (Task $task)
{
    if ($this->tasks->contains($task)) {
        $this->tasks->remove($task);
        $task->removeCategory($this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't work (no errors but still I can't save tasks when I edit category). Are you sure that I don't need additional code in Controllers? How controller should know how to save Tasks from Category add new/edit form?

Comment: I assumed that you use Symfony Forms Component with e.g. a `category` field which is a `EntityType`. Example for your TaskForm: `$builder->add("categories", EntityType::class, array(
                "class" => Category::class,
                "choice_label" => "name",
                "multiple" => true
            ))`  - handling this n:m relation between Task <=> Category should then be handled automatically (if your entities are properly configured).